# Layer over background and images

Tags: css, background, background-image

On my site I have created sort of a landscape with several images (houses, clouds etc) put over the background (a blue sky). However, I want to be able to put a semi transparent layer on top of everything to make the landscape to stand out less (i.e less saturation).

On top of everything are some textboxes (i.e. questions, it's a forum) that shouldn't be affected by the layer. They are the reason for me to want to do this because I want the questions to stand out from the background.

How could this be done?

```
<div class="questions questions-index">
    <div class="action-container container">
        <img class="pic cloud-rainbows" src="/static/images/cloud-rainbow.png" />
        ...
        ...
        <div>
           Text boxes that shouldn't be affected by the layer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.questions-index {
    background-color: #8CBDE6;
    color:white;
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2); */ this works, but only for the background not the images
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You can use `opacity`, look at the example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/3pc7eduv/)